# auto indent in vscode, with 2 spaces as indentation (and not 4)

Tags: visual-studio-code

i'm trying to auto-indent code in vscode, using alt+shift+f (i'm in OSX) and it works, only the indentation is 4 spaces instead of 2 which is what I want.
I set `"editor.tabSize": 2` in settings.js (both user settings and workspace settings), but it seems to have no effect on automatic indentation.

How can I auto-indent using 2-spaces-indentation?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

V 1.0.0: Click on 'Spaces:' on the bottom status bar, select 'indent using spaces' and then select the number of spaces you want.